# Deserialize JSON object as .NET HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Here's an example of raw JSON data:

```
{ "Standards": { "1": "1" } }
```

I want to deserialize the data to:

```
public class Model
{
    public HashSet<String> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

The `Standards` field actually has the `Dictionary<String, String>` type. Somehow the keys and values are always equal. As the types are incompatible, I'm looking for a way to perform a custom deserialization of this field.

A solution based on JSON.NET library is preferred.

P.S.: I have no control over the data serialization process.

Comment: You can always write your own `JsonConverter` and mark the property with `JsonConverterAttribute` if required functionality does not exist already.

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json); are you try like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can handle this with a custom [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm).  Here is the code you would need:

```
public class CustomHashSetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(HashSet<string>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        return new HashSet<string>(jo.Properties().Select(p => p.Name));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        HashSet<string> hashSet = (HashSet<string>)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject(hashSet.Select(s => new JProperty(s, s)));
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, add a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to your model like this:

```
public class Model
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomHashSetConverter))]
    public HashSet<string> Standards { get; set; }
}
```

Then, just deserialize as normal and it should work:

```
Model model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(json);
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tvHt5Y

Comment: You may want to have `ReadJson` throw an exception if the name and value don't match. Just in case you get a value that does not have the same key and value.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.

Comment: What about: `{ "Standards": [ "1", "2", "3" ] }` ?

Comment: @Vinigas What about it?  You don't need a converter for that JSON-- it is compatible with `HashSet<string>` already.  https://dotnetfiddle.net/eCijSK