# How to store HashSet in cookie

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serialization, asp.net-core-mvc, hashset

ASP.NET 5 MVC shopping cart should allow to select products for comparison.

Controller

```cs
public class CompareController : ControllerBase
{
    const string CompareCookie = "Compare";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets list of products to compare
    /// </summary>
    HashSet<string> Get()
    {
        // cannot convert from 'out System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' to 'out string?'   
        if (Request.Cookies.TryGetValue(CompareCookie, out HashSet<string> res))
            return res;
        return new HashSet<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds product to compare list if it does not exist in list.
    /// </summary>
    void Set(string product)
    {
        var hashSet = Get();
        hashSet.Add(product);
        // Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>' to 'string' via
        // a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, 
        // wrapping conversion, or null type conversion
        Response.Cookies.Append(CompareCookie, hashSet as string);
    }
}
```

Causes compile errors shown in comments since HasSet cannot converted to string and back.

How to allow users to select products in compare and store selected product ids? Is it reasonable to store selected product list in cookie?
Or should Sessions enabled and HasSet should stored in session without serialization ?

Comment: You could serialize it as a JSON array.

Comment: Is there some builtin method which allows how to serialize/deserialize HashSet to/from JSON array ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize JSON object as .NET HashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592254/deserialize-json-object-as-net-hashset)